# What is the best way to design this? Floats or is there a better way? Picture attached

Tags: html, css, frameworks

Sorry about the roughness of the image, but each box will be in a div in my website. I want it be responsive so work well on different screen sizes, so i know i will have to use % when defining the width of each div, but is using floats the correct way to go? Is there a easier way to do this than just floating the divs? And I'm not sure if that will work either.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOuYF.jpg]

Comment: Sorry i didn't make that clear, i just want advice on how to achieve what is in the image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this I would use a few more divs:  [image: Revised layout sketch]

Your largest div will float left; then the two outlined in blue (my additions), also floated left.  Inside of these blue divs, add your own two or three divs, no floats.  This is the simplest way I know to get this layout to work.  For the best results, keep all your styles in a stylesheet for improved caching and maintenance effort.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to design this with floating divs assigned widths using percentages. You instead could design a CSS class for the various types of platforms you hope to support and then toggle them using CSS media queries. This is how modern frameworks like Twitter Bootstrap accomplish this task.

For example : http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive